# Separating list items to right and left in a single UL

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a UL used as a menu, in this I have several list items and I want to separate them to the right and left of page, i.e. the menu items will be on right and log in links on the left, although I can't find the attribute used to do this thing, I tried aligning the LI to the left but with no success and tried defining them as separate class and floating him but again they don't move to the left.

Any help with the right css attributes?

thanks alot in advance,

anton.

```
<li>
<a href="@" class="logon">page4</a>
</li>

li.class{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Could you make a small demo of the problem?  Try http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your css code like

```
li > a {

     float:right;
}
```

Comment: That will float the `a` within the `li`, not to the right of the `ul` (which I assume, from the minimal data provided, that he wants).

Answer (score 0):

guys thanks alot for the help, i finally maneged fixing it, the problem was that i floated my UL LI attributes defining #menu before them, as soon as i deleted this declaration it moved to the left using class.